# Making a div appear on button click (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am a first poster here so please excuse my noob-like behavior.

I have a `button` on my website that when pressed should disappear, and a form should be echoed out in its place without a page refresh.

I have easily achieved this with JavaScript / AJAX, but if JavaScript is disabled, I still want the button to do it's task.

My question is: Can I do this only using PHP, **WITHOUT** a page refresh?

Comment: PHP isn't client side. So no PHP isn't on the site when the button is clicked.

Comment: The only alternative would be to display the div on hover instead of on click. That way you can do it purely with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a way I think you'd want to do it, but you could use an iframe that contains the button. The button would be a link or form submit and the navigation would happen inside the iframe to your form. This way, only the iframe is refreshed, but the full page remains unchanged.

Comment: I think a more standard way to make it unobtrusive would be to make the button submit the page and showing the form on a full page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot comment or I would have but the answer would be no. PHP is server side so the only way for it to update a view is to reload to a new page. Also, I would think it is very unlikely to run into a situation where JS is disabled these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can only aciehcve this using ajax. You can force your users to enable 
javascript `noscript` tags

```
      <noscript>
           <p>This page requires a JavaScript-enabled browser.</p>
       </noscript>
```